# "Hallar el mayor y menor número en un vector". Al ejecutarlo me lee los números que le ingreso y luego sale error y no imprime el resultado

Tags: java, array

```
/*
Hacer un programa que imprima el mayor y el menor de los elementos de un vector de longitud n
*/
package taller_arreglos_ejercicio1_logica;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Taller_Arreglos_Ejercicio1_Logica {

    static int MayMen[];
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int n;
        n=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese la cantidad de elementos a ingresar"));
        MayMen=new int [n];
        LeerVec();
        Mayor();
    }

    public static void LeerVec(){
        for (int i=0; i<=MayMen.length; i++){
           MayMen[i]=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese el número "+i));

        }
       }

    public static void Mayor(){
        int i, May;
        May=MayMen[0];

        for (i=1; i<MayMen.length;i++){

           if (MayMen[i] >= May){
               May=MayMen[i];

           }  

        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Mayor: "+May);
    }

    public static void Menor(){
        int i, Men;
        Men=MayMen[0];
        for (i=1; i<MayMen.length; i++){
            if(MayMen[i] <= Men){
                Men=MayMen[i];
            }
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Menor: "+Men);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dentro del método `LeerVec()` (Java aconseja empezar el nombre de los métodos en minúscula), el bucle `for` cuenta desde 0 hasta `MayMen.length`. Por lo tanto, sobre pasa en 1 el límite y cuando intenta apuntar a una posición más alta del array, te devuelve un error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Intenta reescribirlo así:

```
for (int i=0; i<MayMen.length; i++){
```

Comment: De verdad que me has ayudado. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

```
package matriz;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MATRIZ {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x, y, may = 0, men = 0;
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        int M1[][] = new int[4][4];
        for (x = 0; x < 4; x++) {

            for (y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
                M1[x][y] = leer.nextInt();
                if (x == 0 && y == 0) {
                    may = M1[x][y];
                    men = M1[x][y];
                }
                if (M1[x][y] > may) {
                    may = M1[x][y];
                }

                if (M1[x][y] < men) {
                    men = M1[x][y];
                }

            }

        }
        System.out.println("el menor es: " + men + "el mayor es: " + may);
    }

}
```